# Can anyone identify producer of this rotary sieve?

Tags: compost, tools

I am trying to find the producer of this rotary sieve (image found on now defunct [hotbin blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20230222131104/https://hotbincomposting.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/all-three-compost-products-after-using-sifter.jpg)). It is mentioned that it is a Belgian, but not more than that.

[image: image of the sieve]

I'd be also happy with pointers to similar devices available in Europe.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Seems that [these](https://rollingsifter.ecwid.com/) are sold to europe at an additional cost.

[image]

I didnt buy one myself, saw it on "[Self Sufficient Me](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yeGACnQCDnY)" channel that I trust, he is on Australia and the company is American so you might be lucky if there ain't any local supplier.